# Boot Mode Problem In dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

So months ago, i had an ssd installed in my system, and the guy re installed windows in legacy mode on my ssd. Now as i have developed need for Linux for development, I installed ubuntu in my hard driv in uefi mode, Now when my boot mode is legacy windows run fine, but no grub menu is shown, and when i turn legacy off, only ubuntu is shown, when i click on windows boot from grub menu, it goes in an infinity loop of Automatic Repair.

Please help me and suggest me some solutions as i dont want to lose any data and need to use both os.

Thanks

Comment: If your system is less than 10 years old "the guy" did not know what he was doing. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. So most hardware is now UEFI. And how you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is how it installs. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I suspect your best option is to reinstall Windows as uefi. However, whatever you do, losing your data (your big concern) isn’t an issue - **you really must make a backup now, before you mess with your boot / OS etc.** Once you’ve done that, you can reinstall Windows or try any other fix without worrying about data loss.